# How to I get Shopify to convert a cart.total_order value into USD before applying it to a piece of code?

Tags: shopify, liquid, currency, shopping-cart

**Warning: I am not a programmer. A lot of what I have managed to do is through research and trial and error.**

I use Shopify for my website platform and I provide free shipping for orders over $50 USD. I created a very basic piece of code on my cart page that tells a customer how close they are to free shipping:

```
{% if cart.total_price >= 5000 %}
    <div class="shipping-notice">You'll receive FREE SHIPPING to the contiguous US &amp; Canada!</div>
{% elsif cart.total_price < 5000 %}
    <div class="shipping-notice">You're only {{ 5000 | minus: cart.total_price | money }} away from FREE SHIPPING to the contiguous US &amp; Canada!</div>
{% endif %}
```

Recently, I installed a currency converter app and the numbers in the message mess up because it is just seeing the `5000` as a number and not a value in USD. (It is saying a person that has £38.00 GBP in cart has £12.00 GBP left to free shipping)

How do I change the code so the cart.total_price value converts to USD before being applied to the code?

**Simple terms are preferred. As I said, I'm not a programmer.**

Answer (score 0):

You could make the calculation of how much money needed in the view, and pass that to the template as a variable. Then check if the amount in the cart is around that value.

ie:

```
def get(self, request):
    cart = 1.00
    free_shipping = 5000
    if "Great Britain":
        free_shipping = free_shipping * float(1 / 0.75)
    else:
        pass
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'free_shipping' : free_shipping, 'cart' : cart})


{% if cart.total_price >= free_shipping %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: But that does not make it very accurate since Shopify has constantly changing exchange rates. Is there a variable or something that I can use to call up the most current exchange rate? (Something like "currency.exchange_rate"?)

Comment: You need to calculate the value of free shipping prior to sending it to the view. If Shopify has an exchange rate converter or not, you'll need to calculate the level at which free shipping become available to the customer. You probably can use another python library to calculate the exchange rate, and make sure shopify passes you the region the customer is requesting from. There's probably a better way, but that's how i'd do it.